# duplicate row.names after deleting and adding back rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(id = as.integer(integer()),
                   points = as.integer(integer()),
                   row.names = 1,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

When adding IDs, if given ID already exists their points are set to predefined constant max_points, otherwise if given ID does not exist it's created:

```
IDs <- c(1,2,3,20,30,55)     # assume these values has been generated
df[IDs, ] <- max_points
```

If points in some rows reach zero, the rows are removed:

```
df <- subset(df, points > 0)
```

However after certain rows are deleted and later at some point new value is added back to their place, the duplicate row.names error shows up:

```
> df
   points
7    2
8    2
13   2
14   2
15   2
16   2
17   2
18   2
> df[13, ] <- 13
> df
Error in data.frame(points = c(" 2", " 2", " 2", " 2", " 2", " 2", " 2",  : 
  duplicate row.names: 13
```

Upon futher inspection the new dataframe looks like this:

```
    points
 7    2 
 8    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
16    2
17    2 
18    2
 9   NA
10   NA
11   NA
12   NA
13   13
```

Why does it behave this way? Is there any way around this?

**EDIT**

To reproduce the problem here's a code snippet:

```
IDs <- c(13,14,15,8,16,17,18,7)
df <- data.frame(ID = as.integer(integer()),
                       points = as.integer(integer()),
                       row.names = 1,
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df[IDs, ] <- 2
df <- subset(df, points > 0)
df[13, ] <- 13
```

Comment: What's `max_points`?

Comment: As pointed by David you are using an object which is not stated here so we can't run the code to debug, can you check your question and update it?

Comment: @DavidArenburg As written in my post: it's  _predefined constant_ set to some number at the beginning of my script. For instance `max_points <- 5`

Comment: @GGA I edited my code and added a code snippet you can run to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the problem arises in this line

```
df[13,] <- 13
```

Here, you are assigning a value to the thirteenth row. Since your df has less rows, additional NA rows are created in between. I think, you wanted to assign the value to the row named "13", hence

```
df["13",] <- 13
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes this solved my problem. Using `df[as.character(IDs), ] <- max_points` solved my problem.